# What's the term for saving values of calculations instead of recalculating multiple times?

Tags: optimization, terminology, temporary-objects

When you have code like this (written in java, but applicable to any similar language):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        total += i * doStuff(i % 2); // multiplies i times doStuff(remainder of i / 2)
}

public static int doStuff(int i) {
    // Lots of complicated calculations
}
```

You can see that there's room for improvement. `doStuff(i % 2)` only returns two different values - one for `doStuff(0)` on even numbers and one for `doStuff(1)` on odd numbers. Therefore you're wasting a lot of computation time/power on recalculating those values each time by saying `doStuff(i % 2)`. You can improve like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int total = 0;
    boolean[] alreadyCalculated = new boolean[2];
    int[] results = new int[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        if (!alreadyCalculated[i % 2]) {
            results[i % 2] = doStuff(i % 2);
            alreadyCalculated[i % 2] = true;
        }
        total += i * results[i % 2];
    }
}
```

Now it accesses a stored value instead of recalculating each time. It might seem silly to keep arrays like that, but for cases like looping from, say, `i = 0, i < 500` and you're checking `i % 32` each time, or something, an array is an elegant approach.

Is there a term for this kind of code optimization? I'd like to read up more on the different forms and the conventions of it but I'm lacking a concise description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a term for this kind of code optimization?

Yes, there is:

> In computing, **memoization** is an optimization technique used primarily to speed up computer programs by storing the results of expensive function calls and returning the cached result when the same inputs occur again.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization

Answer (score 1):

Common-subexpression-elimination (CSE) is related to this.  This case is a combination of that and hoisting a loop-invariant calculation out of a loop.

I'd agree with CBroe that you could call this specific form of caching memoization, esp the way you're implementing it with the clunky `alreadyCalculated` array.  You can optimize that away since you know which calls will be new values and which will be repeats.  Normally you'd implement memoization with a static array inside the called function, for the benefit of all callers.  Ideally there's a sentinel value you can use to mark entries which don't have a result computed yet, instead of maintaining a separate array for that.  Or for a sparse set of input values, just use a hash (instead of e.g. an array with 2^32 entries).

You can also avoid the `if` in the main loop.

```
public class Optim
{
  public static int doStuff(int i) { return (i+5) << 1; }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    int total = 0;
    int results[] = new int[2];

    // more interesting if we pretend the loop count isn't known to be > 1, so avoiding calling doStuff(1) for n=1 is useful.
    // otherwise you'd just do int[] results = { doStuff(0), doStuff(1) };

    int n = 50;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < Math.min(n, 2) ; i++) {
        results[i] = doStuff(i);
        total += i * results[i];
    }
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) { // runs zero times if n < 2
        total += i * results[i % 2];
    }
    System.out.print(total);
  }
}
```

Of course, in this case we can optimize a lot further.  `sum(0..n) = n * (n+1) / 2`, so we can use that to get a closed-form (non-looping) solution in terms of `doStuff(0)` (sum of the even terms) and `doStuff(1)` (sum of the odd terms).  So we only need the two `doStuff()` results once each, avoiding any need to memoize.